# Running a mpi python script in IPython

Tags: python, parallel-processing, ipython, mpi4py

I've a simple script as follows:

```
#hello.py
from mpi4py import MPI
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
print("hello world from process ", rank)
```

I want to run it in a IPython Notebook with multiple processors. How can do it ?